# STL Refresh After Editing

Tags: import, file-format, stl

I have two separate stl's I am "blending" in blender.

#One stl stays the same while I adjust stl #Two in freecad to fit the curves of #One.
The problem I am having is that I would like to just refresh stl #Two as it sits upon #One without having to close #Two and reimport it.

Is it possible to refresh/reload a file?

In a Cura Slicer, for example, once the file is resaved the adjustments are applied and visually noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Blender. You could make a script using Python and Blender's Python API to do that.

```
import bpy, os


C = bpy.context
C.scene["STL_file"] = "C:\\Users\\m\\Desktop\\STL.stl"
C.scene["timestamp"] = 0
C.scene["object"] = None


def reload_STL_if_changed():
    if C.scene["timestamp"] != os.stat(C.scene["STL_file"]).st_mtime:
        if C.scene["object"] != None:
            override = C.copy()
            override["selected_objects"] = [C.scene["object"]]
            with C.temp_override(**override):
                bpy.ops.object.delete()

        bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath = C.scene["STL_file"])
        C.scene["object"] = C.object
        C.scene["timestamp"] = os.stat(C.scene["STL_file"]).st_mtime
        return 5.0
    return 2.0

#try: bpy.app.timers.unregister(bpy.reload_STL_if_changed) 
#except: pass

bpy.app.timers.register(reload_STL_if_changed)
#bpy.reload_STL_if_changed = reload_STL_if_changed
```